# What is . and .. in Unix/Linux?

Tags: command-line, directory, dot-files

What is `.` and `..` in Unix/Linux ?

I’m making a confusion here: the `..` (dots) means one dot for the current directory and one dot for the parent directory? That why `cd ..` goes back one above? From the current to one up?

And also why the one dot and two dots is displayed this way: `.` `..` current
directory and one up? It makes more sense to me like this: `..` `.` one up, current directory, then the files and directories…

Please explain me this a bit more.

Comment: Related: [Why was '.' chosen to represent the current directory and '..' for parent directory?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/61984)

Comment: `ls -a` sorts directory entries in lexical order (dependent on the locale's collation order). So `.` comes before `..`. After `touch + .+`, you'll likely see that `ls -a` shows `+ . .+ ..` as `+` often sorts before `.`

Comment: `It makes more sense to me like this:` why? and why is it an issue?

Answer (score 4):

Your supposition is exactly right:

- `.` is the current directory.
- `..` is the parent directory, which is the typical term for the directory in which the current directory can be found.

As for why `.` is usually displayed before `..`, it has to do with lexical ordering, which is similar to alphabetization so I shall use that as an analogy:  `.` is ordered before `..` for the same reason that `a` would be alphabetized before `aa`.